Workbench not opening on the Desktop
I have installed Mysql on my system using the normal documentation procedures and instructions. I have also downloaded the Mysql workbench also by following instruction from Msql documentation website.
Please help.
But after running 'Mysql-workbench' its showing this error 'zsh: command not found: mysql-workbench'.
Then clicking on the workbench icon from the app drawer or on the desktop. It does not open.
I have also tried 'nano ~/.zshrc 'and 'source ~/.zshrc' to edit the PATH but to avail
enter image description here
